# Bohr radius and it's relationship with electron -electron interaction

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism

If the kinetic energy and potential energy of electron is the same, electrons are separated by Bohr radius. But then why first orbit of hydrogen atom is at distance of Bohr radius even though the kinetic energy and potential energy of electron is different in the first orbit?

Comment: Which model are you using two discuss this? Atomic hydrogen has only one electron, and dihydrogen molecule 2 protons. Bohr model is very crude when considering multielectron configuration !
In a more general point of view , do you know that two electrons atoms very easily exhibits autoionising states, (that is to say meta stable bounded states that are efficiently coupled to state where on electron is ejected with positive energy) ?

Comment: Are you comfortable to discuss your question on the basis of Schrödinger's equation?

Comment: In a hydrogen atom, the potential energy of the electron is negative, and has twice the magnitude of the kinetic energy.